Error Opening .nsys-rep File: ProtobufParseException and Version Compatibility Issue in NVIDIA Nsight Systems
I am trying to open a .nsys-rep report file in NVIDIA Nsight Systems, but I encounter the following error:
Failed to load report view from: **/report.nsys-rep  
The report was possibly created with a newer version of NVIDIA System Profiler. Please upgrade to the latest version and try again.  

/dvs/p4/build/sw/devtools/Agora/Rel/CUDA12.6/QuadD/Common/ProtobufComm/Common/ProtobufUtils.cpp(73): Throw in function void QuadDProtobufUtils::ReadMessage(QuadDProtobufUtils::PbCodedIStream&, QuadDProtobufUtils::PbMessageLite&)  
Dynamic exception type: boost::wrapexcept<QuadDCommon::ProtobufParseException>  
std::exception::what: ProtobufParseException

I suspect this might be due to a version mismatch between the tool and the file, but I am unsure how to resolve this.

How can I fix this issue and open the report file?
Is there a way to identify the version of Nsight Systems used to generate the .nsys-rep file?

Any guidance on resolving this issue and best practices for handling Nsight Systems report compatibility would be greatly appreciated.
